# convert plain text password login to hash

Tags: php, hash, authentication, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

I am working on a PHP script for my site, the site it's self is up and running. The problem I have is that the registration on the website is for plain text passwords. Obviously this is very weak security. I am hoping someone can help me convert it so I can use a hash password.
I have included part of the registration code that I think counts. I did not include all code on the page as I did not think it relevant but will supply if someone thinks it will help.

```
require 'include.inc';
if ($signup) {

if ($signup[repassword] != $signup[password]) {
    $err_msg = "Your passwords do not match.";
error($err_msg);
}

if(!preg_match("^[_\.0-9a-z-]+$/i^", $str)) {
$msg = 'Invalid Username! Usernames can consist of letters and numbers only';
}
if(!preg_match("^[_\.0-9a-z-]+$^",$signup[password])) {
   $err_msg = "Invalid Password!  Passwords can consist of letters and numbers   only.";
}
  if(!$signup[password] || !$signup[username] || !$signup[email] || !$signup[username])
        $err_msg = "Oops! You forgot some important fields!";


  if (!$err_msg) {
$usercheck = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO user values(
    'NULL','$signup[fname]','$signup[lname]',
    '$signup[username]','$signup[password]','$signup[email]', 1, ".$pointInc.",     '$signup[referral]', NOW(), 'n', 'y')");

      // done, you are entered correctly, Now Enter the points and URL info


        $sql = "Select id from user where username='$signup[username]'";

    $result = mysql_query( $sql );
        if ( $result != false )
            {
        while ( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
        {
            $point_set = $data['id'];

            }
        } else {
            echo mysql_error();
        }   
    // add rerral points

if ($signup[referral])  {
  $referralSql="UPDATE points SET points=points+ ".$refPoints . " WHERE     userid=".$signup[referral];
  $result = mysql_query( $referralSql );
                if ( $result != false )
                    {
                } else {
                    echo mysql_error();
                    }
    }                           


// add URL  

$sql="INSERT INTO url_table ( userid, website, active, datechanged) VALUES ($point_set,'".$signup[site_url]."','n', '".date("Ymd")."')";

  $result = mysql_query( $sql );
                if ( $result != false )
                    {
                } else {
                    echo mysql_error();
                }
// add points
    $sql="INSERT INTO points (userid, username, points) VALUES ($point_set,'     ',$signPoints)";
  $result = mysql_query( $sql );
                if ( $result != false )
                    {
                } else {
                    echo mysql_error();
                    }
    }
     echo mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."<br>";





            if (!$usercheck) {
       $err_msg = "Database error:<br>There was an error entering your account.<br>It is possible that username or Email already exists, please try another one.<br>";
         }   else {
            include ("reg.php"); 
            exit;
            }
     }
     if (!$err_msg) {
        // done, you are entered correctly



     }
   pageHeader($title, $bgColor, $styleSheet);
?>
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: `Passwords can consist of letters and numbers   only`  .. That is _extremely_ wrong.

Comment: Don't restrict the characters that I can have in my password.... it restricts me, adds to the complexity of your code, reduces security, and is completely unnecessary

Comment: Creating a hash for a string is easy and asked many times, just [search around on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+hash+password)!

Comment: try this link http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php or http://phpmaster.com/password-hashing-in-php/

Answer (score 2):

The basic principle is quite easy:

1 . When a user registers, don't store the plaintext password, but `hash(password)`.

```
$query = $pdoObject->prepare('INSERT INTO users (UserName, Password) VALUES (:u, :p)');
$query->bindParam(':u', $_POST['username']);
$query->bindParam(':p', hash($_POST['password']));
// Note that we don't store the password, we store the hash of the password. Once this script is done executing, no one involved in the website (except for the original user) will know that the password is
$query->execute();
```

2 . When a user attempts to log in, calculate the hash of the entered password with the hash stored in your user database. If both hashes match, the password is correct.

```
$query = $pdoObject->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = :u AND Password = :p');
$query->bindParam(':u', $_POST['username']);
$query->bindParam(':p', hash($_POST['password']));
// We locate the original user by searching for the hash of the password that they typed in
```

So much for theory. Some practical issues you should consider:

1. Many tutorials suggest using MD5 of SHA1 as hash functions. However, **[these are not secure](http://www.securityfocus.com/blogs/262)**. Check the [PHP hash library](http://php.net/hash) (especially the `hash()` function) for available hashing algorithms.
2. You should also consider using [salted passwords](http://php.net/hash). For each registered user, create a random string (the *salt*), concatenate this string with the user's password and then hash both password and salt (the salt needs to be saved too, because you need it again when authenticating the user).
3. You can use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) to make your SQL more secure. This will protect you against something called `SQL Injection`. If you don't do this, then users will be able to mess up your website by entering characters such as apostrophes (`'`).

Comment: as long as you don't protect your login form from external requests it will be open for brute force tryouts with plain passwords and it does not matter how you hash or crypt the password in the db.

Comment: True, but on-line brute force attacks are extremely ineffective, because you can only try out passwords at a very limited rate (due to bandwidth, latency, server capacities, ...). So usually, a brute force attempt on a login form will not be successfull within a reasonable amount of time. Strong hash algorithms are usually strong enough to withstand even offline brute force attacks (which require that an attacker gets his hands on the password hashes) in which an attacker can try out millions of different hashes per second...

Answer (score 0):

You can use md5 function to create a hash for your passwords, example:

```
$password = '12345';
$password = md5($password);
```

You save this hash at the database and when you will check user and password for login you do this

```
$post['password'] = md5($post['password']);
```

and check if is equal of the hash saved in the database.
I know that md5 is not the best hash but is simple and has a good level of security

Comment: Using plain MD5 as hashing algorithm is **extremely insecure**. MD5 hashes can be computed extremely fast (making brute force easy) and the algorithm is prone to collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`crypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) for hashing passwords.

Answer (score -1):

Use md5 for that http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Also look up uniqid http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

It's always a bad practice to store the password in plain text in your database. Check this other question:
[What are the best practices to encrypt passwords stored in MySql using PhP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494234/what-are-the-best-practices-to-encrypt-passwords-stored-in-mysql-using-php)

Comment: What's the point in using uniqid for hashing? Anyway, +1 for pointing to better resources.

Comment: md5 is reeally not a good choice for hashing passwords.

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello it's for giving the asker more insight on security. Thanks :)

Comment: @troelskn yes, but it's a good way to start reading, learning, also noone's going to try and crack a site which has code looking like that

Answer (score -1):

some opinions don't think md5 or SHA-1 breakable, try to salt them.. search that.

Comment: No. Do not use SHA1 or MD5.